# Check cluster worker stopped by accident or suicide

Tags: node.js, multithreading, memory, memory-leaks, cluster-computing

I use `suicide` and `exitedAfterDisconnect` to distinguish the process killed by accident or not:

```
cluster.on('disconnect', function(worker) {
    console.log('' + worker.id + ' disconnect, restart now');
    cluster.fork();
});
cluster.on('exit', function(worker) {
    //if accidental exit
    //是否意外退出
    if (worker.exitedAfterDisconnect || worker.suicide) {
        console.info('process exit by kill');
    } else {
        console.info('process exit by accident');
        cluster.fork();
    }
    console.info('process exit');
});
```

Cause I manually disconnect the worker and fork a new worker. So I have to distinguished the worker is stoped by accident or by the logic.

But I found that, even I manually distinct it with `cluster.worker.disconnect()`, the `worker.exitedAfterDisconnect` and `worker.suicide` are still false or undefined!

My node version is `4.6.2`。

Then, I modify my code by adding one line in disconnect callback:

```
cluster.on('disconnect', function(worker) {
    console.log('' + worker.id + ' disconnect, restart now');
    worker.isSuicide = true;
    cluster.fork();
});
cluster.on('exit', function(worker) {
    //if accidental exit
    //是否意外退出
    if (worker.isSuicide) {
        console.info('process exit by kill');
    } else {
        console.info('process exit by accident');
        cluster.fork();
    }
    console.info('process exit');
});
```

I add `isSuicide` flag to worker object, and check it in exit callback.

It seem to work, but I don't know whether this is a good solution, and I don't know why I can not get the right `worker.exitedAfterDisconnect` and `worker.suicide` status.

I can post my library below. What I want to do is just restart process when memory limit exceed:

```
var cluster = require('cluster');
var usage = require('usage');
var os = require('os');

var CPU_COUNT = process.env.CPU_COUNT;
var CHECK_INTERVAL = process.env.CHECK_INTERVAL;

var cpuCount = CPU_COUNT || os.cpus().length;
var checkInterval = CHECK_INTERVAL || 5000;

module.exports = {
    run: function(bytes, runFunc, cleanFunc) {

        if (cluster.isMaster) {
            for (var i = 0; i < cpuCount; i++) {
                cluster.fork();
            }
            cluster.on('disconnect', function(worker) {
                console.log('' + worker.id + ' disconnect, restart now');
                worker.isSuicide = true;
                cluster.fork();
            });
            cluster.on('exit', function(worker) {
                //if accidental exit
                //是否意外退出
                if (worker.isSuicide) {
                    console.info('process exit by kill');
                } else {
                    console.info('process exit by accident');
                    cluster.fork();
                }
                console.info('process exit');
            });
        } else {

            runFunc && runFunc();

            var killing = false;
            setInterval(function() {

                usage.lookup(process.pid, function(err, result) {

                    if (result === null || result === undefined) {
                        console.log("memory check fail");
                        return;
                    }
                    if (parseInt(result.memory) > bytes && killing === false) {
                        console.log("memory exceed, start to kill");

                        //stop process
                        //杀死进程
                        var killtimer = setTimeout(function() {
                            console.info("process down!")
                            process.exit(1);
                        }, 5000);

                        //prevent no quit，https://cnodejs.org/topic/570924d294b38dcb3c09a7a0
                        //防止阻塞
                        killtimer.unref();

                        cleanFunc && cleanFunc();

                        try {
                            if (['disconnected', 'dead'].indexOf(cluster.workder.state) < 0) {
                                cluster.worker.disconnect();
                            }
                        } catch (err) {};

                        killing = true;
                    }
                });

            }, checkInterval);
        }

    }
}
```

Calling Example:

```
var memory = require('./memory');

//100M LIMIT
memory.run(100000000, function() {
    require('./server.js');
}, function() {
    console.info('clean now!');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is a bit late, but when I was searching google for help I found this as one of the top links. Since I figured out how to do it without setting a custom flag `window.isSuicide` I thought I would share.

Since each `worker` is actually a seperate thread on the os level with a seperate pid, when the `worker` dies it has an exit code. When the worker dies it will, as expected, have an exit code of `1`. If it dies peacefully it will have an exit code of `0`, therefore just check the exit code.

Example Code:

```
var cluster = require('cluster');

// Code to run if we're in the master process
if (cluster.isMaster) {
  startWorkers();
// Code to run if we're in a worker process
} else {
  // For example if the first worker dies of an Exception
  if (cluster.worker.id == 1) {
    throw new Exception("Oh no");
  // Or just exit with an error
  } else if (cluster.worker.id == 2) {
    process.exit(1);
  }
  process.exit();
  // You can also use the following, but they are identical:
  //process.exit(0);
}

function startWorkers () {
  var workerCount = 2;

  for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      cluster.fork();
  }

  cluster.on('exit', function (worker) {
    if (worker['process']['exitCode'] === 0) {
      console.log("Worker %d died peacefully...", worker.id);
    } else {
      console.log("Worker %d died with exit code %d, restarting it", worker.id, worker['process']['exitCode']);
      cluster.fork();
    }
  });
}
```

Will have the following console output:

```
/tmp/tmp.js:10
    throw new Exception("Oh no");
              ^

ReferenceError: Exception is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/tmp/tmp.js:10:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
    at startup (node.js:140:18)
    at node.js:1043:3
Worker 2 died with exit code 1, restarting it
Worker 1 died with exit code 1, restarting it
Worker 3 died peacefully...
Worker 4 died peacefully...
```